# Implement a local maven library into a gradle project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar, gradle-kotlin-dsl

a library I need is currently not working and I have to build and publish it locally. I need dependency libraryA which requires libraryB which is missing .aar in the official release. When I build it locally both libraryB (with the .aar) and libraryA are present.

The error I am getting

```
Failed building KotlinMPPGradleModel
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find firebase-app-debug.aar (dev.gitlive:firebase-app-android-debug:1.4.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dev/gitlive/firebase-app-android-debug/1.4.1/firebase-app-android-debug-1.4.1.aar
```

The file is obviously present here

[image]

I have `mavenLocal` listed in the repositories

I somehow have to get this library into my project

[image]

Trying [to resolve this issue](https://github.com/GitLiveApp/firebase-kotlin-sdk/issues/200)

Comment: Any chance you post the relevant gradle dependency block? One thing that maven local doesn't do which a real maven does is handling the transitive dependencies etc...  Also, local builds will use intermediate files instead of exploding AARs so just because it works locally doesn't mean it's going to work the same when pulled from a real Maven.

Comment: @Shark seems this was rather cumbersome to setup so I went to an older version of the library. I'll leave the question up as it may get an answer helpful to someone as I havent found anything posted yet. Not sure what you mean by relevant dependency block. I just want to implement the FIrebase-Auth which depends on Firebase-App.